# What is an example to demonstrate the need for synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have been telling a colleague that he should synchronize the methods of a data structure because it is being updated from different threads and then queried in yet another thread. He argued that there is no need to do that because the threads all write to different fields and the values are only read after all the threads that write them have finished.

Now according to my twenty year old understanding of the Java Memory Model that is definitely wrong. Without synchronization it is possible for one thread to write a value, and another thread (after the first thread has finished) not to see that value, if no synchronization has been done. I'm pretty confident in my understanding of how it worked back then.

I also think it's still just a good general principle to always synchronize multithreaded access to a shared data structure. But I need better arguments to convince my colleague.

However I know a lot of work has been done on the Java Memory Model since then, making it do the correct thing in more default cases, so my first question is: is my understanding still correct? Should you still use `synchronized` in simple cases like this (thread A updating a field and thread B reading that field after thread A has finished)?

And secondly I'm looking for example code that demonstrates the need for this type of synchronization. Something that does *not* use synchronization and demonstrates a thread reading the wrong value after another thread has already definitely written that value. I tried to write something myself, but I can't get it to break. All the examples I can find only are examples of the *use* of synchronization, not examples of what goes wrong if you don't. The ones I tried all still worked even without synchronization, possibly because they are old and the Java Memory Model has improved since then to make it just work.

Can someone provide a simple example of data access going wrong in this way in the face of a lack of synchronization? Also, what are some good recent sources to read about the current state of synchronization or the Java Memory Model?

Comment: "and the values are only read after all the threads that write them have finished." It depends: if you check finished using `Thread.join()` in the thread that is going to read the values, there is a happens-before relationship, so it would be safe. It feels pretty brittle, though.

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html)

Comment: It is hard to tell whether a code is valid or not based only on a vague description of that code. As for "suggest an example", I bet Stack Overflow is a not the right place for such requests.

Comment: Re, "Without synchronization it is possible for [thread A] to write a value, and [then thread B fails to see the value after thread A has finished.]" If thread B calls `A.join()`, that _is_ synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is, technically, right. Or, rather, s/he can be under some circumstances.

The relevant question is whether there is a [happens-before relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) between the write and the read of the shared variables.

For example, one such case that establishes the relationship would be if the thread doing the reading calls `join` on the thread doing the writing to ensure it has finished before attempting to read the value.

> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

Under these circumstances, it would be safe. For example:

```
class Foo {
  int a;

  void test() {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> { a = 1; });

    t.start();

    // ...

    System.out.println(a); // Might print 0 or 1.

    // ...

    // This means that everything done by the thread happens before
    // everything that happens after this line. So, the write to `a`
    // happens before the read of `a`.
    t.join(); 

    System.out.println(a); // Will print 1, unless some other thread interferes with its value.

  }

}
```

I wouldn't call this good practice, however: it's pretty brittle, because it relies on you not trying to read the value anywhere other than in the thread doing the `join`-ing.

Unless it can be proven that it is an unacceptable performance issue to synchronize, I would.

But, actually, I think it would be better not to deal with multithreaded things at such a low level: use an `ExecutorService`, submit `Callable`s to it which return the value that the thread would have written, and use the `Future` returned to obtain the result.